# How to cache a react page with static assets using Python?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, caching

I created a flask application that makes a GET request to https://create-react-app-example.vercel.app and caches the react page.
Then serve the HTML page from cache.

Flask App:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests_cache

app = Flask(__name__)
session = requests_cache.CachedSession('react_page')

@app.route("/")
def serve_react_page():    
    return session.get('https://create-react-app-example.vercel.app').text

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Flask App dependencies:

```
Flask==1.1.2
requests-cache==0.8.1
```

I'm not able to cache the contents from the static folder.

```
dineshsonachalam@macbook % python3 proxy.py
 * Serving Flask app "proxy" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET /static/css/main.5f361e03.chunk.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET /static/js/2.087e98bc.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET /static/js/main.26bec6bc.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET /static/js/2.087e98bc.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET /static/js/main.26bec6bc.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2021 23:09:40] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

[image]

A react build will contain static folders to store CSS, js, and images.

```
dineshsonachalam@macbook ui % tree build 
build
├── asset-manifest.json
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── logo192.png
├── logo512.png
├── manifest.json
├── robots.txt
└── static
    ├── css
    │   ├── main.a617e044.chunk.css
    │   └── main.a617e044.chunk.css.map
    └── js
        ├── 2.d4015c87.chunk.js
        ├── 2.d4015c87.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
        ├── 2.d4015c87.chunk.js.map
        ├── 3.b4494d53.chunk.js
        ├── 3.b4494d53.chunk.js.map
        ├── main.3dbeb9be.chunk.js
        ├── main.3dbeb9be.chunk.js.map
        ├── runtime-main.5d34aaab.js
        └── runtime-main.5d34aaab.js.map

3 directories, 18 files
```

Is there are any way to cache the contents from the static folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serve_react_page` here is returning what the user would see when they navigate to that page. Which includes links to files in `/static`.

That page has links to the static assets, and when it looks for them, it's asking *your* server for what's actually on for instance `https://create-react-app-example.vercel.app/static/css/main.5f361e03.chunk.css`.

But the browser wants to find it at `http://0.0.0.0:5000/static/css/main.5f361e03.chunk.css` which of course does not exist.

You could try to set up a route in your flask app, that any request to `/static` downloads the file from `https://create-react-app-example.vercel.app` and serves it cached to the client.